# SkiaSharp Map with Map Marker Buttons

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, pan, skiasharp

I am currently trying to make a map like canvas with buttons inside using SkiaSharp and Xamarin.Forms.

but when it comes to zoom / pan i can't sync this 2 up because when

a) im using a control with zoom / pan actions and canvas + buttons as childs with inverse scale, that mostly works but the skiasharp canvas will be blurry because it's only an element transform (bitmap scaling)

b) the buttons don't stay at the desired location when using the direct skiasharp canvas transform and a seperate content container for the buttons because (bad) transform syncing

any idea on how to combine this 2 components to a map with button markers like element?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use AbsoluteLayouts to stack Xamarin.Forms buttons (or Images with GestureRecognizers) over the top of a drawn SKCanvas. Each time a button is clicked you then have to eventually call InvalidateSurface() on the SKCanvas and it will redraw with the parameters that were changed by the clicking of the button. I'm doing this a lot in an app of mine and am very happy with it, you can see it [over here](https://github.com/KRA2008/crosscam).